# How can I do waypoint movements in xcom 2?

Tags: xcom-2

> **Moderator Note:** For controller instructions, see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286982/how-can-i-do-waypoint-movements-in-xcom-2-console-version). For iOS, see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382454/how-can-i-do-waypoint-movements-on-xcom-2-on-ios).

I've seen some streamers do a waypoint movement, where you can move along a specific route in a single action. How do I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hold Ctrl while selecting tiles to set a specific movement path.

Comment: Tried shift, cursed, and alt+f4'd my ironman game.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for consoles?

Answer (score 9):

Dunno if this is still active, but the console equivalent is to hold "A" or "Square" and move the left stick