# How can I do waypoint movements in XCOM 2 (console version)?

Tags: controllers, xcom-2

> **Moderator Note:** For iOS instructions, see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382454/how-can-i-do-waypoint-movements-on-xcom-2-on-ios).

[On the PC, it's possible to set waypoints in XCOM 2 using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254337/how-can-i-do-waypoint-movements-in-xcom-2)

Is it possible to do the same on the PS4 / Xbone versions and if so how do you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In an official Xcom 2 news posting](https://xcom.com/news/new-update-deployed-for-xcom-2-on-ps4-xbox-one) regarding an update to PS4 and Xbox One versions, the first item listed under "GAMEPLAY" is

> Waypoint functionality added.

I played the Xbox One version last night and was able to add a waypoint by pressing and holding the A button; presumably the PS4 version's X button would support the same functionality.

At of the time of this writing, I couldn't find any updates to either [the PS4 or Xbox One online game manuals](https://www.2k.com/manual/xcom2/) and I don't remember seeing any in-game notifications indicating that this new feature was available.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't sound like you can.

I played this game on PC, so I know what you're talking about. I looked around a bit, and the best evidence I found was actually [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/554ex7/the_lack_of_ability_to_create_waypoints_on/), entitled "The lack of ability to create waypoints on consoles is a pretty big oversight".

Since so many people on Reddit are so eager to tell people that they're wrong and that they're idiots, I think someone probably would have chimed in to say that waypoints are possible if that were the case. Instead, we have a bunch of people complaining about the lack of the feature while other people tell them that it's not needed (and that they're idiots).

Comment: Yeah sadly, I think you are right. I have been searching since I asked and haven't found anything either.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, it's long press A on Xbox controller

Comment: This probably would be better as a comment on [Brian's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/293134/7562). I am not going to downvote you though because you probably can't post comments yet. [Which I still think is dumb](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment).