# How can I do waypoint movements on XCOM 2 on iOS?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I can't figure out how to set waypoints in the iOS (i'm on iPad specifically) version of XCOM 2.

[How can I do waypoint movements in XCOM-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254337/how-can-i-do-waypoint-movements-in-xcom-2) seems to cover this for PC, and [How can I do waypoint movements in XCOM 2 (console version)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286982/how-can-i-do-waypoint-movements-in-xcom-2-console-version) addresses it on home consoles, but neither cover iOS.

I'm *fairly* sure it's possible because I think I did it by accident once and was confused by the weird path, but can't for the life of me figure out how.

Comment: Annoyingly enough, looks like the [official online manuals](https://www.2k.com/manual/xcom2/collection/) don't include iOS. Can't seem to find an iOS manual anywhere.

Comment: @Wipqozn the iOS version has WEIRDLY minimal in-game training or documentation.  It feels like the most comprehensive source of knowledge is the tooltips, which... ain't an ideal medium for reference or browsing.